# is it possible to control frame rate on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, view

I was animating a ball bouncing on the screen moving an UIView by setting its origin property but I found that the movement of the ball was not smooth. I checked the frequency at which drawInRect was being called and it was 30 times/s, which I don't consider enough to make a fast ball movement smooth.

My question is, is it possible to ask the system to refresh/redraw the screen at 60fps? Can you do the same in OpenGL?

Comment: If you're using UIImage's `-drawInRect` to refresh the ball's position, be aware that Core Graphics redrawing is a very expensive operation and not what you'll want for any kind of animation. Draw the object once and only move its containing view or layer after that.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider setting up a display link function.  This will allow you to fire a method for every draw call that comes through the system (or every certain number of frames).  The class you want to deal with is CADisplayLink, and [here](https://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/drawing-with-cadisplaylink/) is a tutorial.  If your animation is not fast enough with this still, then your animation is never going to look smooth ;).

Answer (score -1):

You Don't need to change the fps of ios to get your animation right .You simply need to change it in YOu code , you can do it using NSTimer (An Example):-

Initialize a timer on Some Animation :-

```
    float theInterval = 1.0/30.0;//Here you can set the frame rate , now set on 30
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:theInterval target:self
        selector:@selector(animateView:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    - (void)animateView:(NSTimer *)theTimer 
    {
    //    your animation block here....
    Something like..
    view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x+viewMovement.x,
                    view.center.y+viewMovement.y);

        BOOL collision = view.center.y >= view2.center.y - 16 &&
        view.center.y <= view2.center.y + 16 &&
        view.center.x > view2.center.x - 32 &&
        view.center.x < view2.center.x + 32;

    if(collision)
        viewMovement.y = -viewMovement.y

}
```

It'Just an example , implement your logic accordingly.

Comment: This is a very bad advice. At the end of the drawing code, the system will block the rendering thread until display refresh, so this timer will either pile up drawing commands, or add stuttering. **NEVER** use system timers for controlling animation! You should always *measure* the time between frames, and advance the animation accordingly.

Comment: I just gave an example and by the way i made a game on it , using this code works like charm , you can always invalidate the timer based upon your condition...no need to vote down here .. is it..Well NSthread woulb be anice idea 2...

Comment: In addition to what datenwolf said, you really should be using a CADisplayLink if you're going to have some kind of timer for display refreshes. NSTimer is not synchronized with the display refresh, like CADisplayLink, and you won't be able to get the smoothest display refresh if using NSTimer.